# beamer headerline shadow?

Tags: beamer, themes

I'm trying to modify shadow in headerline and I need some spaces between left and right side in footline and headline.

what I have done so far:
[image]

And i like similar to show in bottom image form and i need framewidth between headline and footline left and right to be decrease pt in size.

[image]

%%%%%%%%% Here my code .TEX AND BELOW ru.sty %%%%%%%%%%%%

```
    \documentclass{beamer}

  \usepackage[british]{babel}
 \usepackage{graphicx,hyperref,ru,url}

      \title[RU style for Beamer]{
   Radboud University style for Beamer \LaTeX}

  \subtitle{Show where you're from}

  \author[Pim Vullers MSc]{
     Pim Vullers MSc \and Martijn Sprengers \\\medskip
   {\small \url{p.vullers@cs.ru.nl} \and \url{m.sprengers@student.ru.nl}} \\
   {\small \url{http://www.cs.ru.nl/~pim/}}}

   \institute[Radboud University Nijmegen]{
   Institute for Computing and Information Sciences -- Digital Security \\
   Radboud University Nijmegen}

    \date[slides Example 2011]{
    the 2nd example presentation 2011 \\
    21st March 2010}

  \begin{document}

   \begin{frame}[plain]
    \titlepage
   \end{frame}


   \begin{frame}
      \frametitle{Introduction}

      \begin{itemize}
        \item This is just a short example
      \item The comments in the \LaTeX\ file are most important
     \item This is just the result after running pdflatex
    \item The style is based on the webpage \url{http://www.ru.nl/}
   \end{itemize}
   \end{frame}















                %%%%% HERE CODE FOR **ru.sty**  %%%%%%%%%%




                 \usetheme{Rochester}
                 \RequirePackage{pgf}
               \pgfdeclareimage[width=1.0\paperwidth]{header-logo}{ru_header}
              \setbeamercovered{transparent}

                 % Layout scheme for outer elements: split header and footer
              \useoutertheme{split}

    % Color scheme for outer elements: use background colors
         \usecolortheme{whale}

       % Layout scheme for inner elements: rounded elements
        \useinnertheme{rounded}

        % Color scheme for inner elements: use foreground colors
   \usecolortheme{orchid}


          %%%
        %%% Tweak definitions of inner theme to match personal preferences (MODIFY THESE)
            %%%

          % Itemize items: default (triangle), circle, square, ball
       \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]

             % Enumerate items: default, circle, square, ball
         \setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[circle]

           % Outline: default, sections numbered, subsections numbered, circle, square, ball, ball unnumbered
            \setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[default]

             % General blocks:
       \setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded]

        % Title page:
        \setbeamertemplate{title page}[default]                  [colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=true,ht=10ex]

            % Part page:
        \setbeamertemplate{part page}[default][colsep=-4bp]

         % Navigation symbols:
       \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}  %it is omit navigation in bottom


          %%%
        %%% Tweak definitions of outer theme to match Radboud (website) style
        %%%



               % Colors now red
        \usecolortheme[RGB={190,49,26}]{structure}

        %frametitle = red and frametitle right = black
         \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{parent=subsection in head/foot}
        \setbeamercolor{frametitle right}{parent=section in head/foot}

        %Added by Martijn Sprengers
 \definecolor{rured}{HTML}{BE311A}
       \setbeamercolor*{Title bar}{fg=white}
       \setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{parent=Title bar}

          % Footline: AUTHOR | TITLE | DATE FRAMENUMBER

       \defbeamertemplate*{footline}{ru theme}{%
        \leavevmode%
      \hbox{%
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.25\paperwidth,ht=5.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.25\paperwidth,ht=5.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
   \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortdate
   \end{beamercolorbox}%
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.416667\paperwidth,ht=5.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
     \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
   \end{beamercolorbox}%
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.083333\paperwidth,ht=5.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{title     head/foot}%
             \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex}
           \end{beamercolorbox}}%
         \vskip0pt%
      }

     %Added by Martijn Sprengers:
         \beamer@headheight=0.13\paperwidth


       \defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{ru theme}
     {
      \vskip-0.25\beamer@headheight
      \vskip-\baselineskip
      %\hskip0.5cm
       \vskip-0.2cm
         \hskip0.7cm\usebeamerfont*{frametitle}\insertframetitle
         \vskip-0.10em
      \hskip0.7cm\usebeamerfont*{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle
      }

       \defbeamertemplate*{headline}{ru theme}{%

  \pgfuseimage{header-logo}
   \vskip -1.95cm
   \linethickness{0pt}

 \framelatex{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=0.3\beamer@headheight]{Title bar}
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}%
   \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{0pt}{\hskip0.22cm}{}%
   \end{beamercolorbox}}

  \framelatex{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=0.9\beamer@headheight]{Title bar}
         \end{beamercolorbox}}
  }
```

Comment: Could you divide your code in two fragments? What's the name of your style? How do you load it?

Comment: ru.sty it's in below . i mentioned with                                                       %%%%% HERE CODE FOR .STY  %%%%%%%%%%

Comment: @Ignasi: Though the content is same, the questions are different IMO. So I  feel that this need not be closed.